# What prefix characters can I search on in Trello?

Tags: trello

I'd like to use Tags in Trello (#tagname) and then search on them.

But, of the ones I've tried, only _ works (_keyword).
Not idea.

I've tried $ # & * ( ! > .  (and - is a "negative" search prefix)

It looks like maybe #keyword will be saved as a Power feature but just hoping :

Comment: `#` is used to search for labels (try `#blue`, for example).  Is there a reason those won't work for you?

Comment: @AaronDufour, there is a limit of about 8 labels (colors). AND the labels are not universal, so I'm guessing that I can't use #LabelName on Board1 and Board2 unless it's been defined in both.

Comment: #color works universally (as do #1-#6, corresponding to the keyboard shortcut that adds the label).  #LabelName will find cards from any board with a label matching that name (yes, you have to name it on each board).  [More Labels/Tags](https://trello.com/c/ylDBKS2F/1059-more-labels-tags) is in progress.